# How to implement random search optimization for a MLPClassifier?

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn

I am new to optimization and have been trying to learn random search. After studying some theory i tried to implement it in a MLPClassifier that i had previously worked on.

```
def hyperparameter_tune(clf, parameters, iterations, X, y):
  randomSearch = RandomizedSearchCV(clf, param_distributions=parameters, n_jobs=-1, n_iter=iterations, cv=6) 
  randomSearch.fit(X,y)
  params = randomSearch.best_params_
  score = randomSearch.best_score_
  return params, score
```

this method returns the best set of paramters and the best score after performing randomized search on the given dataset.

```
parameters = {
    'nohn': [150,200,250,300],
    'solver': ['sgd', 'adam', 'lbfgs'],
    'activation': ['relu', 'tanh']
}
clf = MLPClassifier(batch_size=256, verbose=True, early_stopping=True)
parameters_after_tuning, score_after_tuning = hyperparameter_tune(MLPClassifier, parameters, 20, X_train_pca, y);
print(score)
```

At first I just wanted to optimized number of hidden neurons, solver and activation function for the MLPClassifier. So i have assigned other parameters like batch_size a fixed value when creating the classifier. But when i pass the classifier to hyperparamter_tune method i get the following error

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-18-a0c800c38881> in <module>()
      1 clf = MLPClassifier()
----> 2 parameters_after_tuning, score_after_tuning = tuning(MLPClassifier, parameters, 20, X_train_pca, y);
      3 print(score)

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/sklearn/base.py in clone(estimator, safe)
     65                             "it does not seem to be a scikit-learn estimator "
     66                             "as it does not implement a 'get_params' methods."
---> 67                             % (repr(estimator), type(estimator)))
     68     klass = estimator.__class__
     69     new_object_params = estimator.get_params(deep=False)

TypeError: Cannot clone object '<class 'sklearn.neural_network._multilayer_perceptron.MLPClassifier'>' (type <class 'abc.ABCMeta'>): it does not seem to be a scikit-learn estimator as it does not implement a 'get_params' methods.
```

Can anyone help me out. There are most likely a lot of things that I could do better in my code. I would love to hear any suggestions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are more than one bugs in your code.

1. You're passing `MLPClassifier` class to `hyperparameter_tune` instead `clf`.
2. There's no `nohn` parameter for MLP!
3. You're printing `score` which doesn't exist.

Here's a minimal example which runs:

```
from sklearn.model_selection import RandomizedSearchCV
from sklearn.neural_network import MLPClassifier
import numpy as np

def hyperparameter_tune(clf, parameters, iterations, X, y):
  randomSearch = RandomizedSearchCV(clf, param_distributions=parameters, n_jobs=-1, n_iter=iterations, cv=2) 
  randomSearch.fit(X,y)
  params = randomSearch.best_params_
  score = randomSearch.best_score_
  return params, score


parameters = {
    'solver': ['sgd', 'adam', 'lbfgs'],
    'activation': ['relu', 'tanh']
}
clf = MLPClassifier(batch_size=256, verbose=True, early_stopping=True)

X_train_pca = np.random.randn(6,2)
y = [0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1]
parameters_after_tuning, score_after_tuning = hyperparameter_tune(clf, parameters, 20, X_train_pca, y);
print(score_after_tuning)
```